# CAS ServiceManagement: Unauthorized Service Access

Tags: java, maven, cas

I'm trying to configure CAS server using this [Maven CAS overlay installation guide](http://jasig.github.io/cas/4.0.x/installation/Maven-Overlay-Installation.html), but I have faced with one problem - when I enter my CAS credentials I receive the following message in cas web page:

> Application Not Authorized to Use CAS
>
> The application you attempted to authenticate to is not authorized to
>   use CAS.

User has been authorized successfully but service could not be authorized.

Catalina.out presents the following warning message:

```
[scheduler_Worker-2] INFO org.jasig.cas.services.DefaultServicesManagerImpl - Loaded 9 services.
Hibernate: select trim(password) from system_users where username=?
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] INFO org.jasig.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager - QueryDatabaseAuthenticationHandler successfully authenticated test+password
Hibernate: SELECT * FROM system_users WHERE username = ?
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] INFO org.jasig.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager - Authenticated test with credentials [test+password].
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] INFO com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: audit:unknown
WHAT: supplied credentials: [test+password]
ACTION: AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Oct 28 09:55:46 GMT 2015
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 10.10.11.115
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 10.10.11.113
=============================================================


[http-nio-8080-exec-3] INFO com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: audit:unknown
WHAT: TGT-1-Ogj40oX5SQRVr6AHdJkStF5Oo0S4ESB96ExrOkIaGmeQ2rFafi-cas01.example.org
ACTION: TICKET_GRANTING_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Oct 28 09:55:46 GMT 2015
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 10.10.11.115
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 10.10.11.113
=============================================================


[http-nio-8080-exec-3] WARN org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl - ServiceManagement: Unauthorized Service Access. Service [http://localhost/app/j_spring_cas_security_check] is not found in service registry.
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] INFO com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: test
WHAT: http://localhost/app/j_spring_cas_security_check
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_NOT_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Oct 28 09:55:46 GMT 2015
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 10.10.11.115
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 10.10.11.113
=============================================================


[http-nio-8080-exec-5] WARN org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl - ServiceManagement: Unauthorized Service Access. Service [http://localhost/app/j_spring_cas_security_check] is not found in service registry.
[http-nio-8080-exec-5] INFO com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: test
WHAT: http://localhost/app/j_spring_cas_security_check
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_NOT_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Oct 28 09:55:50 GMT 2015
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 10.10.11.115
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 10.10.11.113
=============================================================
```

I cannot figure out how is necessary to configure service registry in my case. Any ideas?

My cas.properties:

```
server.name=http://localhost:8080
server.prefix=${server.name}/cas
# IP address or CIDR subnet allowed to access the /status URI of CAS that exposes health check information
cas.securityContext.status.allowedSubnet=127.0.0.1


cas.themeResolver.defaultThemeName=cas-theme-default
cas.viewResolver.basename=default_views

##
# Unique CAS node name
# host.name is used to generate unique Service Ticket IDs and SAMLArtifacts.  This is usually set to the specific
# hostname of the machine running the CAS node, but it could be any label so long as it is unique in the cluster.
host.name=cas01.example.org

##
# Database flavors for Hibernate
#
# One of these is needed if you are storing Services or Tickets in an RDBMS via JPA.
#
# database.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
# database.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
database.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

##
# CAS Logout Behavior
# WEB-INF/cas-servlet.xml
#
# Specify whether CAS should redirect to the specified service parameter on /logout requests
# cas.logout.followServiceRedirects=false

##
# Single Sign-On Session Timeouts
# Defaults sourced from WEB-INF/spring-configuration/ticketExpirationPolices.xml
#
# Maximum session timeout - TGT will expire in maxTimeToLiveInSeconds regardless of usage
# tgt.maxTimeToLiveInSeconds=28800
#
# Idle session timeout -  TGT will expire sooner than maxTimeToLiveInSeconds if no further requests
# for STs occur within timeToKillInSeconds
# tgt.timeToKillInSeconds=7200

##
# Service Ticket Timeout
# Default sourced from WEB-INF/spring-configuration/ticketExpirationPolices.xml
#
# Service Ticket timeout - typically kept short as a control against replay attacks, default is 10s.  You'll want to
# increase this timeout if you are manually testing service ticket creation/validation via tamperdata or similar tools
# st.timeToKillInSeconds=10

##
# Single Logout Out Callbacks
# Default sourced from WEB-INF/spring-configuration/argumentExtractorsConfiguration.xml
#
# To turn off all back channel SLO requests set slo.disabled to true
# slo.callbacks.disabled=false

##
# Service Registry Periodic Reloading Scheduler
# Default sourced from WEB-INF/spring-configuration/applicationContext.xml
#
# Force a startup delay of 2 minutes.
# service.registry.quartz.reloader.startDelay=120000
# 
# Reload services every 2 minutes
# service.registry.quartz.reloader.repeatInterval=120000

##
# Log4j
# Default sourced from WEB-INF/spring-configuration/log4jConfiguration.xml:
#
# It is often time helpful to externalize log4j.xml to a system path to preserve settings between upgrades.
# e.g. log4j.config.location=/etc/cas/log4j.xml
# log4j.config.location=classpath:log4j.xml
#
# log4j refresh interval in millis
# log4j.refresh.interval=60000

##
# Password Policy
#
# Warn all users of expiration date regardless of warningDays value.
password.policy.warnAll=false

# Threshold number of days to begin displaying password expiration warnings.
password.policy.warningDays=30

# URL to which the user will be redirected to change the passsword.
#password.policy.url=https://password.example.edu/change
password.policy.url=http://fix.me
```

My deployerConfigContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
| deployerConfigContext.xml centralizes into one file some of the declarative configuration that
| all CAS deployers will need to modify.
|
| This file declares some of the Spring-managed JavaBeans that make up a CAS deployment.  
| The beans declared in this file are instantiated at context initialization time by the Spring 
| ContextLoaderListener declared in web.xml.  It finds this file because this
| file is among those declared in the context parameter "contextConfigLocation".
|
| By far the most common change you will need to make in this file is to change the last bean
| declaration to replace the default authentication handler with
| one implementing your approach for authenticating usernames and passwords.
+-->

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <!--
       | The authentication manager defines security policy for authentication by specifying at a minimum
       | the authentication handlers that will be used to authenticate credential. While the AuthenticationManager
       | interface supports plugging in another implementation, the default PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager should
       | be sufficient in most cases.
       +-->
    <bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager">
        <constructor-arg>
            <map>
                <!--
                   | IMPORTANT
                   | Every handler requires a unique name.
                   | If more than one instance of the same handler class is configured, you must explicitly
                   | set its name to something other than its default name (typically the simple class name).
                   -->
                <entry key-ref="proxyAuthenticationHandler" value-ref="proxyPrincipalResolver" />
                <entry key-ref="primaryAuthenticationHandler" value-ref="primaryPrincipalResolver" />
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>

        <!-- Uncomment the metadata populator to allow clearpass to capture and cache the password
             This switch effectively will turn on clearpass.
        <property name="authenticationMetaDataPopulators">
           <util:list>
              <bean class="org.jasig.cas.extension.clearpass.CacheCredentialsMetaDataPopulator"
                    c:credentialCache-ref="encryptedMap" />
           </util:list>
        </property>
        -->

        <!--
           | Defines the security policy around authentication. Some alternative policies that ship with CAS:
           |
           | * NotPreventedAuthenticationPolicy - all credential must either pass or fail authentication
           | * AllAuthenticationPolicy - all presented credential must be authenticated successfully
           | * RequiredHandlerAuthenticationPolicy - specifies a handler that must authenticate its credential to pass
           -->
        <property name="authenticationPolicy">
            <bean class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.AnyAuthenticationPolicy" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Required for proxy ticket mechanism. -->
    <bean id="proxyAuthenticationHandler"
          class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.HttpBasedServiceCredentialsAuthenticationHandler"
          p:httpClient-ref="httpClient"
          p:requireSecure="false"
            />

    <!--
       | TODO: Replace this component with one suitable for your enviroment.
       |
       | This component provides authentication for the kind of credential used in your environment. In most cases
       | credential is a username/password pair that lives in a system of record like an LDAP directory.
       | The most common authentication handler beans:
       |
       | * org.jasig.cas.authentication.LdapAuthenticationHandler
       | * org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.QueryDatabaseAuthenticationHandler
       | * org.jasig.cas.adaptors.x509.authentication.handler.support.X509CredentialsAuthenticationHandler
       | * org.jasig.cas.support.spnego.authentication.handler.support.JCIFSSpnegoAuthenticationHandler
       -->
    <bean id="primaryAuthenticationHandler"
          class="org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.QueryDatabaseAuthenticationHandler">
        <property name="passwordEncoder">
            <bean
                    class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.DefaultPasswordEncoder">
                <constructor-arg value="MD5" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="sql" value="select trim(password) from system_users where username=?" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" >
            <value>org.postgresql.Driver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>jdbc:postgresql://m-test-db:5432/casdb</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>admin</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>qwe123</value>
        </property>
    </bean>




    <!-- Required for proxy ticket mechanism -->
    <bean id="proxyPrincipalResolver"
          class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.BasicPrincipalResolver" />

    <!--
       | Resolves a principal from a credential using an attribute repository that is configured to resolve
       | against a deployer-specific store (e.g. LDAP).
       -->
    <bean id="primaryPrincipalResolver"
          class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.PersonDirectoryPrincipalResolver" >
        <property name="attributeRepository" ref="attributeRepository" />
    </bean>

    <!--
    Bean that defines the attributes that a service may return.  This example uses the Stub/Mock version.  A real implementation
    may go against a database or LDAP server.  The id should remain "attributeRepository" though.
    +-->
    <bean id="attributeRepository" class="org.jasig.services.persondir.support.jdbc.SingleRowJdbcPersonAttributeDao">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="dataSource" />
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="SELECT * FROM system_users WHERE {0}" />
        <property name="queryAttributeMapping">
            <map>
                <entry key="username" value="username" />
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="resultAttributeMapping">
            <map>
                <entry key="username" value="username" />
                <entry key="first_name" value="FirstName" />
                <entry key="last_name" value="LastName" />
                <entry key="active" value="active" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <util:map id="attrRepoBackingMap">
        <entry key="uid" value="uid" />
        <entry key="eduPersonAffiliation" value="eduPersonAffiliation" />
        <entry key="groupMembership" value="groupMembership" />
    </util:map>


    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
    <bean id="serviceRegistryDao"
          class="org.jasig.cas.services.JpaServiceRegistryDaoImpl"
            /><!--
      p:entityManager-ref="entityManager"
      -->
    <!--
  <bean id="entityManager"
    factory-bean="entityManagerFactory"
    factory-method="getEntityManagerInterface"/>
-->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">

        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>org.jasig.cas.services</value>
                <value>org.jasig.cas.ticket</value>
                <value>org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.support</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">

        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <util:list id="registeredServicesList">
        <bean class="org.jasig.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService"
              p:id="0" p:name="HTTP and IMAP" p:description="Allows HTTP(S) and IMAP(S) protocols"
              p:serviceId="^(http?|https?|imaps?):/.*" p:evaluationOrder="10000001" />
        <!--
        Use the following definition instead of the above to further restrict access
        to services within your domain (including sub domains).
        Note that example.com must be replaced with the domain you wish to permit.
        This example also demonstrates the configuration of an attribute filter
        that only allows for attributes whose length is 3.
        -->
        <!--
        <bean class="org.jasig.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService">
            <property name="id" value="1" />
            <property name="name" value="HTTP and IMAP on example.com" />
            <property name="description" value="Allows HTTP(S) and IMAP(S) protocols on example.com" />
            <property name="serviceId" value="^(https?|imaps?)://([A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.)*example\.com/.*" />
            <property name="evaluationOrder" value="0" />
            <property name="attributeFilter">
              <bean class="org.jasig.cas.services.support.RegisteredServiceRegexAttributeFilter" c:regex="^\w{3}$" /> 
            </property>
        </bean>
        -->
    </util:list>

    <bean id="auditTrailManager" class="com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager" />

    <bean id="healthCheckMonitor" class="org.jasig.cas.monitor.HealthCheckMonitor" p:monitors-ref="monitorsList" />

    <util:list id="monitorsList">
        <bean class="org.jasig.cas.monitor.MemoryMonitor" p:freeMemoryWarnThreshold="10" />
        <!--
          NOTE
          The following ticket registries support SessionMonitor:
            * DefaultTicketRegistry
            * JpaTicketRegistry
          Remove this monitor if you use an unsupported registry.
        -->
        <bean class="org.jasig.cas.monitor.SessionMonitor"
              p:ticketRegistry-ref="ticketRegistry"
              p:serviceTicketCountWarnThreshold="5000"
              p:sessionCountWarnThreshold="100000" />
    </util:list>
</beans>
```

My POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd ">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>net.unicon</groupId>
    <artifactId>cas-server</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <hibernate.validator.version>4.2.0.Final</hibernate.validator.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>

        <cas.version>4.0.0</cas.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>cas</warName>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-server-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>${cas.version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-server-core</artifactId>
            <version>${cas.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-server-support-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${cas.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1200-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-releases</id>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi I was found this exception today,
my config like this.

```
    <bean id="serviceRegistryDao"
      class="org.jasig.cas.services.InMemoryServiceRegistryDaoImpl"
      p:registeredServices-ref="registeredServicesList" />
    <util:list id="registeredServicesList">
    <bean class="org.jasig.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService"
          p:id="1"
          p:name="jason web application"
          p:serviceId="^(https?|imaps?|http?)://.*"
          p:evaluationOrder="0" />
  </util:list>
```

I think **InMemoryServiceRegistryDaoImpl** this class can solve you problem.